# Is there a cross-platform "port" of the Arduino Serial library?

Tags: c++, serial-port, arduino, porting

I want to port an Arduino library (namely, the HerkuleX servo control library) from Arduino to the PC (namely, a desktop running Linux). Since Arduino libraries are written in C++, this should be fairly easy. However, the HerkuleX library makes use of the Arduino's Serial library, which AFAIK is specific to the hardware. Does anyone know of a cross-platform serial library (like Boost.Asio) with the same API as the Arduino one? I thought for sure it would exist already, but Google failed me. If not, I assume I'll have to pick an existing serial library and make a wrapper around it myself so it behaves like the Arduino Serial library. (That way if the upstream Arduino library is updated, re-porting it to PC won't be too much hassle.)

Comment: Well, this doesn't solve my actual question, but does solve my original problem. I found a desktop C and C++ library for the HerkuleX servo available for download on <http://www.sgbotic.com/index.php?dispatch=products.view&product_id=1128>

Comment: For the record, I couldn't get that library to work, so now I'm working on a wrapper of <https://github.com/wjwwood/serial> that implements the same interface as the Arduino serial library <https://github.com/wmhilton/ArduinoSerialWrapper>.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the Arduino serial library is not portable. The code relies heavily on hardware and the AVR aritechiture of the Arduino. Here is the [source](https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/blob/master/hardware/arduino/cores/arduino/HardwareSerial.cpp) and [header](https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/blob/master/hardware/arduino/cores/arduino/HardwareSerial.h) file. As you can see in the header file it includes functions from the AVR library.